# Using the key prop to force re-mount of a React component

Tags: reactjs, key

We have a case where we need to re-mount a third party component to trigger stuff that happens in the mounting process. Not to confuse with update/rerender that we'd prefer, but we have restricted control over the component.

However, we've been searching around and found that quite many suggest using the key prop and change the value once the component should re-mount. We've tested it out and it seems to work as expected but the thing is that there is no official documentation of this approach at https://reactjs.org, and I have never seen it before. Only together with lists/iterations but not on single elements.

What do you think?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what is third party component's name?

Comment: Did come across this before when using react-intl. Not sure about the docs but the component should update whenever the props supplied is changed and so does the value needs to be updated in UI.

Comment: Agree with @Fawaz. Any third party component shall be designed correctly, and re-mounting approach is sure bad practice.
Except if you are forced to use incorrectly designed component, that's why it's essential to know what component is that.
checking it's sources my lead to answer

Comment: Yeah I agree that it's a bad practice to force re-mounting. The third-party component is the async select in `react-select` v2. There's a configuration `defaultOptions` that you can set to `true` and it'll trigger `loadOptions('')` to get a default set of options. The issue was that it's only triggered initially, which makes complete sense, but when the data updates we want to reflect that in the default options. However, we realized that it's also possible to send in your own array of default options, so it could be solved that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an indirect answer to your question in [React docs](http://%3Chttps://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#tradeoffs%3E).

> Keys should be stable, predictable, and unique. Unstable keys (like those produced by Math.random()) will cause many component instances and DOM nodes to be unnecessarily recreated, which can cause performance degradation and lost state in child components.

So the re-mount behavior is intended. IMHO as part of the reconciliation algorithm, it is also stable.

Answer (score -1):

Using keys only makes sense in lists (arrays) inside JSX. Otherwise this shouldn't have any effect and if it does I wouldn't want to rely on this behaviour in production as I don't think it's intended

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Could you tell us what the third-party library that you are using is? Perhaps there is a better workaround for your problem!

Comment: Yes, that's why I reacted when people suggested to use it outside lists. Here's one article about it https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/p8tr2ah430-forcing-a-child-remount-with-the-key-prop, but the approach isn't documented anywhere. However, managed to solve the actual problem, see my comment in the initial post.